# Unit Test: The cancelation of the test run is not possible as there is no test run which is in progress

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I get the following error when I successfully run unit tests in VS2012:

> The cancelation of the test run is not possible as 
>   there is no test run which is in progress

The error only appears after the unit tests succeeds (green check in visual studio).

Why do I get this error?

Comment: The cancelation of the task known as test run is not possible because either Kraang has not run the task known as test run or Kraang has already completed the task known as test run, in which case Kraang should have known not press the button known as the cancel button.

Comment: @Greg Lol! The farther I get into my career, the more funnier cynical dev humor gets. That being said... I hope there's a better fix for this, because I have the same error. Only it prevents me from seeing my test results :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disable breaking on `InvalidOperationException` in the exceptions dialog.

Visual studio seems to unsuccessfully stop the already finished test, which leads to this error.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question "Why do I get this error". I'm having the same problem can't even view my test results. Disabling breaking on that exception doesn't make the problem go away, it just hides it under the rug :/

Comment: you have a different problem then

Comment: This successfully fixed the issue. In my opinion, it is the correct answer. It doesn't necessarily sweep the problem under the rug, because the InvalidOperationException is happening within the VsTest framework with no impact on the test itself. So clearly the VsTest framework is able to handle this exception internally with no impact on the test. Thus this would seem to be a correct solution, and does not hide any problem -- relevant to the consumer of the framework -- under the rug.

Comment: This is a terrible answer if you have any interest in catching InvalidOperationException within the code that you're actually trying to test.    And it's a fairly common exception in lots of different types of code, so assuming that that exception only happens in MSTest seems pretty naive.  For any code that might throw InvalidOperationException, this "answer" essentially ruins the usefulness of debugging the unit tests to begin with.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using VS 2012 and using the Test Explorer with the NUnit Test Adapter and this error prevented me from being able to debug a failing test. I found a workaround to this issue [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773660/debugging-unit-tests-raises-and-eats-several-exceptions-when-closing)

> To overcome these exceptions:
>
> 1. Navigate to the Debug menu item
> 2. Select "Options and Settings..."
> 3. Check "Enable Just My Code"
>
> As a side note, this also allows you to step-into shimmed code (via
> fakes usage).

Answer (score 2):

I also restarted Visual Studio and the error no longer appeared.

I'm not sure why you would want to disable breaking on InvalidOperationException to fix the problem. What if you actually had an InvalidOperationException in the future?

Answer (score 1):

I restarted Visual Studio and the problem went away.